# When to use delete-request in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I try to understand when to use @delete requst annotation.

When I Try to use @delete its showing me error like "Request method 'GET' not supported"

I've Googled around and read that @getrequest should work. But I dont understand why. My Method is clearly a delete Request. Even without returning a view it gives the same error.

So When to use @delte and when not?

```
@DeleteMapping("/deletetask/{id}")
public String delete(@PathVariable Integer id)
{
    service.deleteById(id);

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> When I Try to use @delete its showing me error like "Request method
>   'GET' not supported"

You sent a GET Http request.
Spring tells you that it is not accepted since the controller method is mapped to the `DELETE` verb :

```
@DeleteMapping("/deletetask/{id}")
```

You have to send a [DELETE Http request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE) such as :

```
DELETE /deletetask/123 HTTP/1.1
```

> So When to use @delete and when not?

In the same source (MDN), it is said that :

> The HTTP DELETE request method deletes the specified resource.

Comment: And it should be `DELETE /task/123`.

Comment: @chrylis agreed. In fact it should be at the origin : `@DeleteMapping("/task/{id}")`

Comment: what do you mean with "DELETE verb" ?

Comment: I dont really understand to be honst. I delete a specified resource from teh database. So it's a deleterequest. Or what specified resource mean,

Comment: Does it mean that DELETE request is just usest to delete real files like html, txt etc? Nothing from the database?

Comment: @Chris The delete verb (or method) makes part of the method that you can use when you send an http request to a server. https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html. You can send a POST, GET, DELETE, ... request. DELETE may be used for any resources. In the scope of Rest services, it can be an abstract resource defined in a database as well as a physical resource.

Comment: @dividxxx So when you say it can be a resource from a datatable und I'm deleting a resource from a datatable (service.deleteById(id)) why can't I use delete request? Do I understand the word resoruce wrong maybe? I understand that a ressouce can be a normal data entry in a database. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC maps HTTP requests to Java code. It creates mappings based on request type and URI ( there are advanced mappings, but it's different topic )

Error that you see happens because you have mapping for HTTP request with type `DELETE`, but you are sending request with type `GET`. There could be different [types of http requests](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

You need to use request type `DELETE`, when you want to delete something. It doesn't matter what: file, record in database or something else. Point here is that you are DELETING. Same works for `GET` ( to get something ), `POST`(to create something) and so on.

According to RESTfull principles you should use resource names in URLS, e.g. if you are working with `tasks` you should have `"/task"` as url and http method as action that you perform on your resource. So to delete

```
@DeleteMapping("/task/{id}")
public String delete(@PathVariable Integer id)
{
...
}
```

To get:

```
@GetMapping("/task/{id}")
public String get(@PathVariable Integer id)
{
...
}
```

and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The point I don't get: yout say 

"You need to use request type DELETE, when you want to delete something. It doesn't matter what: file, record in database or something else. Point here is that you are DELETING."

but as you can see here "service.deleteById(id);" I delete a databse record...

Why you mean I'm not deleting?

The method is not be used for  a Rest-api so it should be finde.

Comment: I guess you missunderstood what @Ivan Lymar means. A good and best practice based rest api is based on conventions and simplicity. Like mentioned in the link of Ivan a rest api should use request methods the describe what the method does . So when you want to request a resouce, use get. If you change an existing resource use put. If you create a new resource use post. If you delete a resource use Delete. The point is that it is self declaring. There are many spring best practice guides eg. https://dzone.com/articles/designing-rest-api-best-practices-you-should-be-fo